# Need Discussion on Dynamic Routes with shallow option next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

Page renders every time when we are trying to update or add queryParms in URL with shallow option. sometimes getting error

> The provided `as` value (null) is incompatible with the `href` value (/search/[country]/[city])

For dynamic routes my folder structure is

```
Search -> Folder Name
   - [country]
     -  [city].js
```

when i am trying to update URL on click

```
  const incrementCounter = () => {
     const currentCounter = query.counter ? parseInt(query.counter) : 0;
    const href = `/search/de/berlin/?counter=${currentCounter + 1}`;
    router.push(pathname, href, { shallow: true });
  };
```

[image]

In my case, on click change state counter my query object in the router not updating with counter params.so, if i will click again then it is not incrementing.

the second case if I will replace pathname with asPath then my URL is updating and query params is updating. Problem is page renders every time on the server.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

[codesandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-faraday-q9p4k?file=/pages/search/%5Bcountry%5D/%5Bcity%5D.js)

1. Page /search/de/berlin
2. Click on change state counter
3. see render page but not updating url
4. See error

### Expected behavior

My current url - `http://localhost:4000/search/de/berlin`
want to add new queryParams: `?counter=3&id=98`

Should not reload the page on the server. should be all params in router query.

System information

- Version of Next.js: Latest
- Version of Node.js: Latest